# Vertical split view and quadrants?

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, split-window

In OS X El Capitan is it possible to use split view in anything other than a horizontal configuration.

I usually work with two 1080p monitors side by side meaning that a horizontal split view has little use to me.

In the past I've used [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) which has been my go to, until this new feature was introduced (check it out if you're the kind of guy that needs pixel perfect window placement to satisfy your OCD).

Is it possible to have the new split view feature in El Capitan work vertically or even better allow for more split views inside split views (*inception*) similar to how iTerm2 splitting works?